# How to add product category via xml

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services

In this xml file how can i add product category? I used `<ProductCategoryId>` tag for this puprpose. But its also showing the error.Can anyone suggest a solution for this..?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>example</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>Product</MessageType>
<PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
<Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<OperationType>Update</OperationType>
<Product>
<SKU>R1000TEST</SKU>
<ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
<DescriptionData>
<Title>test_material name</Title>
<Brand>Applexus</Brand>
<Description>test_material name</Description>
<BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 1</BulletPoint>
<BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 2</BulletPoint>
<MSRP currency="USD">25.19</MSRP>
<Manufacturer>Applexus</Manufacturer>
<ItemType>Wireless</ItemType>
</DescriptionData>
<ProductData>
<Health>
<ProductType>
<HealthMisc>
<Ingredients>Example Ingredients</Ingredients>
<Directions>Example Directions</Directions>
</HealthMisc>
</ProductType>
</Health>
</ProductData>
</Product>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your correct Merchant

```html
<MerchantIdentifier>Corrent_M_ID_e.g_5618548151F487</MerchantIdentifier>
```

Comment: hi..i tried the above code...bt its not giving the result